# PowerPoint - load macro on document load?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

Does anyone know how I can have a macro load on document load when opening a PowerPoint pot-template? I've looked at some `Auto_Open` and add-ins which looks like need to be set. 
But there's a few settings that need to be set as well within PowerPoint itself for it to work. I've got a template which thousands of users are about to be using. And setting these settings sound like a horrible job to do for all users. Adding the add-in, adjusting security settings AND allowing Trust access to Visual Basic Projects (a security setting within PowerPoint). It would be a major problem if everybody need to do all of this manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully done this with an AddIn's Auto_Open method, combined with creating event handlers using the [approach described here](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004.htm).  My plan is to digitally sign the Add-In (to prevent Macro prompts) and the end-users perform the step of loading the Add-In.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked into that :) But would it be possible to roll out this in a massive scale? What would have to be done?